# save() with Original name File

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have some question.
I need to save my file to `storage/public/apps` with original name and not with name `FAJFJAKJ@$!@@!#` - look's like this.

What I missing there??

Controller

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $request->file('file')->save('public/apps');

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'File Upload Successfully!');
}
```

web.php

```
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware('auth')->group(function(){
 Route::get('/', 'Admin\IndexController@index');
 Route::get('dashboard', 'Admin\IndexController@index')->name('dashboard');
 
 
 Route::get('upload-files', 'Admin\UploadController@index');
 Route::post('upload-files', 'Admin\UploadController@upload');
 
 
 Route::get('links', 'Admin\LinkController@index')->name('links');
 Route::get('links/create', 'Admin\LinkController@createUlr')->name('links.create');
 Route::post('links/create', 'Admin\LinkController@store')->name('links.store');
 Route::get('links/{id}', 'Admin\LinkController@linkById')->name('link.chose');
 Route::post('links/{id}', 'Admin\LinkController@update')->name('link.delete');
 Route::delete('links/{id}', 'Admin\LinkController@delete')->name('link.delete');
});
```

Form

```
<form class="col-lg-push-6" action="/admin/upload-files" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
  <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
   <label class="bmd-label-floating">New File</label>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="file" class="form-control" size="100" name="file">
  </div>
  <button  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Create</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: You should start with the [Wikipedia Filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename) page. It has a decent-sized table ([Comparison of filename limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations)), listing the reserved characters for quite a lot of file systems.

Comment: `$request->file('file')->storeAs('directoryName', $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName());`  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files for further read

Comment: @Donkarnash `->storeAs` - publishing answer! Thanks 

Comment: @Donkarnash write your comment as answer, so that we can consider this question is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever handling file uploads in Laravel Controller, below things can be helpful

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{

    //Validate request data if there are other fields as well
    // do not include image fields in validation rules
    $validatedData = $request->validate($rules, $request->except('image'));

    //Check if $request has uploaded file and whether it's a valid file 
    if($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()) {
        //Custom name pattern as per application preference
        $filename = time() . '.' . $request->file('image')->extension();

        //Or - Get the original name of the uploaded file
        $filename = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();

        //Store the file in desired directory and assign the path to the image field in validated data
        $validatedData['image'] = $request->file('image')->storeAs('images', $filename);
    }  

    //Fill the values from validatedData and save the record
    $model->fill($validatedData);
    $model->save();

}
```

Comment: Whattttaaa?! Now my `dd($request->file('file'))` return `[]` - 10 minutes ago all was working!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to upload the file with the original name you can use `getClientOriginalName()` function which will return the original name of file , here is some code which will help to upload your file to your desired location and i would highly recommend to wrapping your paths in **Variables**.

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $imageName = "{$request->file->getClientOriginalName()}.{$request->file->getClientOriginalExtension()}";
    $imagePath = "public/apps/{$imageName}";
    $request->file->move(public_path("public/apps"), $imageName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here you can see below:**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//importing user model
use App\User;

class UploadImage
{
    function avatarUpload(Request $request)
    {


        $file = $request->file('avatar_img');
        //getting original name of file
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $post = [
            'avatar_img'=> $fileName,
            'id'=> $request->user()->id
        ];
        //saving into database
        $create = User::create($post);
        if($create)
        {
            //store file, it will store in avatars folder inside app folder
            $store = $file->storeAs('avatars',$fileName);

            return $store ? 'Avatar image uploaded' : 'Avatar image store failed';
        }
        return 'Avatar image upload failed';        
    }   
}
?>
```